# How to change style of an array element depends on function result in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new here and I am learning programming and I have some doubts about how can I change the style of each function result.
I´m trying to do a poker card that change my elements array for icons depends on the function result and I don´t know how to do it.
Could you help me please?

```js
var cardSuits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'clubs'];
var cardValue = [
    '1','2', '3', '4', 
    '5', '6', '7', '8', 
    '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];

const GenerateRandomCard = () => {
    
    let cardSuitsRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cardSuits.length));
    console.log(cardSuitsRandom);

    let cardValueRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()  * (cardValue.length));

    return '<div>' + cardSuits[cardSuitsRandom] + '</div>' +  '<div>' + cardValue [cardValueRandom] + '</div>' + '<div>'+ cardSuits[cardSuitsRandom] +  '</div>'
};

window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('#cardMap').innerHTML = GenerateRandomCard();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: green
}

#cardMap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 80px auto 10px auto;
    height: 420px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.allCard {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.heartCard {

}

.spadeCard {

}

.diamondCard {

}

.clubCard {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Random Card</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cardMap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you just want to add a class name to your `div` based on the `cardSuits` selected? Just change your HTML so that it produces `<div class="heartCard">` for "hearts". Something like `'<div class="' + cardSuits[cardSuitsRandom] + 'Card">'` should get you close...

Comment: Thank for your reply Heretic.
Sorry but I don´t understand if I put this code, how javascript link each class to each cardSuits?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.allCard{}` with `.card{}`

Use the `.card{}` selector to put all the common styles that should be there regardless of the type of card.

So I guess

```
.card{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And then in your javascript code

```
var element = document.getElementById("cardMap");
element.classList.add(cardSuitsRandom);
```

Will add the classes with the card suit, so if you pull a heart, the class will look like `class="card hearts"`

And then make selectors in your css like

`card.spades{}`, `card.hearts{}`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
return '<div class="'+cardSuits[cardSuitsRandom]+' value-'+cardValue[cardValueRandom]+'"></div>;
```

So you add the results of the randomly generated suit and card value to your returned `<div>`'s classes, and then you style the classes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a CSS rule with each suit, create an array of rule names that map to the suit names:

```js
var cardSuits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'clubs'];
const cardStyles = ['spadeCard', 'diamondCard', 'heartCard', 'clubCard'];
```

Then simply add the class to the div:

```js
return `<div class="${cardStyles[cardSuitsRandom]}">` + ...
};
```

A working example with a few additional styling enhancements:

```js
const cardSuits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'clubs'];
const cardStyles = ['spadeCard', 'diamondCard', 'heartCard', 'clubCard'];
const cardSymbols = ['♠️', '♦️', '♥️', '♣️'];
const cardValue = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];

const GenerateRandomCard = () => {
    
    let cardSuitsRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
      (cardSuits.length));

    let cardValueRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() *
      (cardValue.length));

    return `<div class="${cardStyles[cardSuitsRandom]}">` +
      '<div>' + cardValue[cardValueRandom] + ' ' +
      cardSymbols[cardSuitsRandom] +  '</div></div>'
};

window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('#cardMap').innerHTML =
    GenerateRandomCard();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: green
}

#cardMap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 80px auto 10px auto;
    height: 420px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#cardMap > div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.allCard {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.heartCard {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.spadeCard {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.diamondCard {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.clubCard {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardMap" class="allCard"></div>
```

Comment: I´m trying to do this solution @terrymorse, but I don´t get the result.

Comment: var cardSuits = ['spades', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'clubs'];
var cardValue = [
    '1','2', '3', '4', 
    '5', '6', '7', '8', 
    '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];

const cardStyles = ['spadeCard', 'diamondCard', 'heartCard', 'clubCard'];

Comment: And then my function :
const GenerateRandomCard = () => {
    
    let cardSuitsRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cardSuits.length));
    console.log(cardSuitsRandom);

    let cardValueRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()  * (cardValue.length));

    return `<div class="${cardStyles[cardSuitsRandom]}">` + '<div>' cardvalue[cardValueRandom] '</div>'
};

Comment: @Asanchez-2 I just added a working example with a few more tweaks of your original. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks @therrymorse , it was a great help for me.

I have some "begginer" question...

How can I had icons like the card icons to my var?

I have been reading some documentation about the $ function in Java Script but I don´t understand completly how does it work.

I mean... how the computers know how to apply heartCard styles to heartCard and not to any cardSuits..